# DNS / Webmin / BIND9 & Script Config

Tags: ubuntu, dns, webmin, nameservers

**1- Is My DNS already configured?**

When I open the file: /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 75.101.163.170
        netmask 255.255.254.0
        network 75.101.163.0
        broadcast 75.101.163.255
        gateway 75.101.163.1
        dns-nameservers 60.60.120.223 60.60.120.224
        dns-search serverpronto.com
        pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
```

Is my DNS servers already configured? 
I tried to use the 60.60.120.223 and 60.60.120.224 as ns1 and ns2 nameservers under setnameservers of godaddy.com it returned: **Invalid TLD.**

**2- Doubt about the IP that must go in NS1, NS2 addresses**

I have some doubts about nameservers using Bind under ubuntu 12.04 under a dedicated server machine.

I need to create a script telling the ip address of the nameserver.
Suppose the ip address from the server machine is 75.101.163.170, should I add a ns entry like that?

```
ns1.adomain.com.           IN    A         75.101.163.170
ns2.adomain.com.           IN    A         75.101.163.171
```

What IP address must be put in?

I just have a dedicated server machine ip. 
I don't know how to put these NS1, 2... ips etc.

Should they be the IP Address itself or I can add another IP? If I add another IP I think it's not correct because I just have one dedicate machine with a IP address.
I'm a bit confused about this.

**1- My domain name was bought in GoDaddy.com how to point to they?**

I bought my domain under Godaddy.com.
I know there is an area to set name servers, so I can put nameserver 1, nameserver 2, etc.. addresses.

I should put ns1.adomainexample.com ns1.adomainexample.com

My doubt is: If I configure a domain name server how will godaddy know the ns1.adomainexample.com is related to my machine?

Answer (score 0):

For the last part you need to register your own nameservers with Go Daddy.  Here are the steps to do so:

To Register Your Own Domain Hosts

1. Log in to your Account Manager.
2. Next to Domains, click Launch.
3. Click the domain name you want to use to register as your own nameserver.
4. In the Host Summary section, click add.
5. In Host name, enter the host name you want to register.

   NOTE: The value entered here will be appended to your domain name to create the host name. Do not use the 'www' prefix. Example: For the domain name coolexample.com, entering 'ns1' here results in ns1.coolexample.com.
6. In the Host IP fields, enter the two unique IP addresses you want to add to the host.

   NOTE: Nameservers cannot share an IP address; therefore two unique IP addresses are required.
7. Click OK.

Once you do the above you can then set your domain to point to the custom nameservers you created.  You will also need to add A records in your Zone file for both ns1 and ns2 using the same IP you used above.